# How the XML transformation occurs

Tags: xml, xslt

While transforming the xml using xslt I get result as justin can some body explain the statement  marked as bold below ??

xsl:value-of select="**//*[price='8.20']/@supplier**"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
        <cd supplier="justin">
        <title>Unchain my heart</title>
        <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>EMI</company>
        <price>8.20</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

xslt :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My Supplier</h2>
    <table border="1">
    <xsl:value-of select="//*[price='8.20']/@supplier"/
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` : Any element

`//` : at any hierarchy (the other method is to specify specific XPath

`*[price='8.20']` : Any element having child element `price = '8.20'`

`//*[price='8.20']` : Any element at any hierarchy having child element `price = '8.20'`

`@supplier` : An attribute of name `supplier`

`//*/@supplier` : attribute of name `supplier` under any element at any hierarchy.

`//*[price='8.20']/@supplier` : attribute of name `supplier` under any element at any hierarchy having child element `price = '8.20'` ..

Comment: //*[price='8.20']/@supplier : attribute of name supplier under any element at any hierarchy ok no problem **having child element price = '8.20'** how child element price is under parent element attribute supplier.....

Comment: Ohk. Good question. did you read this? `//*/@supplier` attribute of name supplier under any element at any hierarchy. An attribute will be accessed the way child element is accessed. So `@supplier` under element `cd`, which as at unknown(or any) hierarchy will be like: `//cd/@supplier`..

Comment: whatever you write in the bracket will be noted as condition. example `//cd[price = '8.20']` selects element `cd` which has `child` element price that has value `8.20`. But you want to access attribute `@supplier` under that.. so xpath will be `//cd[price = '8.20']/@supplier`, when you say `//cd[price = '8.20']` you are still under parent `cd` (that has price as 8.20) .. and when you say `//cd[price = '8.20']/@supplier` it will access @supplier **if it exists** ..

Comment: now replace `cd` with `*` in XPath, and now in your xml if you change `cd` element name as `cdcover` it still works, because we haven't specified the element name as cd, but we have specified it as `*` which means it can be any name..

Answer (score 0):

Generally:

```
// - Traverse the whole document

//* - Any element in the document

//*[price = '8.20'] - Any element in the document that has a <price> child element
                      with the value 8.20

//*[price = '8.20']/@supplier - The @supplier attribute of any element in the document 
                                that has a <price> child element with the value 8.20
```

Since there is only one node in the document that matches those criteria, and it has the value "justin", that is why the output is "justin".

Comment: Hi JLRishe I have a doubt in above example we need to extract country name ?? **/catalog/cd/country** that is grandparent->parent->child hierarchy...but here **//*[price='8.20']/@supplier** means **//*[price='8.20']** any price having 8.20 no problem and having attribute supplier why it is comes under price ????

Comment: @BalaMurugan, attribute doesn't come under price element .. it comes under element (`*` means any element) that has price = '8.20'.. whatever you have written within square brackets `[]` will be treated as conditions.. It selects elements with the conditions that is mentioned within those brackets..